# Is there an R function to choose the last row of a group of variables?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Novice user here. I am currently working on a project using R and Tidyverse.

The problem is as such (see example DF below):
I need to select the "Start" and last "End" of each group, and the output should only have 2 rows per group. Each group may have many "End" states. There is a goal DF below.

I played around with conditionals or max() but to no avail. As the current DF is small, I dont mind manually selecting the rows, but when the DF gets larger it will cause a problem.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

**Starting DF**

| Group | State | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start | 1 |
| 1 | End | 2 |
| 1 | End | 3 |
| 2 | Start | 4 |
| 2 | End | 5 |
| 2 | End | 6 |
| 2 | End | 7 |

**Expected DF**

| Group | State | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start | 1 |
| 1 | End | 3 |
| 2 | Start | 4 |
| 2 | End | 7 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want Start to have the lowest Serial, and End to have the highest Serial:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~Group,   ~State,     ~Serial,
1,  "Start", 1,
1,  "End", 2,
1,  "End", 3,
2,  "Start", 4,
2,  "End", 5,
2,  "End", 6,
2,  "End", 7)    

df %>% 
  group_by(Group, State) %>% 
  filter(if_else(State == "START", Serial == min(Serial), Serial == max(Serial))) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Group State Serial
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 Start      1
2     1 End        3
3     2 Start      4
4     2 End        7
```

Answer (score 2):

If `'Start'` is always going to be first row in the group you can select first and last row in each group using `slice` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% slice(1, n()) %>% ungroup

#  Group State Serial
#  <int> <chr>  <int>
#1     1 Start      1
#2     1 End        3
#3     2 Start      4
#4     2 End        7
```

If `'Start'` is not always the first row in the group, you may use `match` to get it's position.

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% slice(match('Start', State), n()) %>% ungroup
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), State = c("Start", 
"End", "End", "Start", "End", "End", "End"), Serial = 1:7), 
row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is always a beginning and an end

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
      State = c("Start",
                "End", "End", "Start", "End", "End", "End"),
      Serial = 1:7
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-7L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(Serial %in% range(Serial)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Group State Serial
#>   <int> <chr>  <int>
#> 1     1 Start      1
#> 2     1 End        3
#> 3     2 Start      4
#> 4     2 End        7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in this shape we could use this code: It will always select the first and last row of a group:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  arrange(Serial) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==n())
```

```
  Group State Serial
  <int> <chr>  <int>
1     1 Start      1
2     1 End        3
3     2 Start      4
4     2 End        7
```